# process.stdin.on('readable' calls callback function 3 times. why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following nodejs code in read.js file

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function () {
    console.log('test');
});

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.resume();
```

when I execute this in terminal like `node read.js` then is outputs

```
test
test
test
```

Why it outputs test 3 times and how can I fix this?

Comment: Well, why shouldn't it? [`readable`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable) is supposed to do that.

Comment: @Bergi is there any alternative method that I could use? Could you give me one?

Comment: If you tell us *what you want to do* we might be able to suggest the most appropriate method for your task.

Comment: I am trying to create command line tool. When user executes this script then it will read through all the files in a folder mentioned by user, then create a new file and put all files contents in this newly created file. But the problem with above approach is that it puts contents of those files 3 times due to readable.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [readline package](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) to get the user input